# How to set the application to be launched back of the UI appl. - C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms (.Net 2.0) application.  While launching UI application it internally launches another .exe. I want my UI application on the top, but right now the other application is showing on the top.

How can I get the UI application to remain on top of (the other executable) while launching the other application?

Comment: Call `this.Activate()` from your form. Although you shouldn't, it's very user-unfriendly.

Comment: You can start/launch as executable by setting `ProcessStartInfo=ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized`

Comment: I am launching my other appl. like this... Process.Start("ServerApps.exe"); what i can set that this will open backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BringToFront()` method for that.
Please see the link below

[C# bring Windows Form to front](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bf3117f8-d83d-4b00-8e4f-7398b559a2dd/)